# Converting array of characters to an array of uint32_t in c-- is this the proper way?

Tags: c, string, type-conversion, int, unsigned

I am trying to convert an array of characters into an array of uint32_t in order to use that in a CRC calculation. I was curious if this is the correct way to do this or if it is dangerous? I have a habit of doing dangerous conversions and I am trying to learn better ways to convert things that are less dangerous :). I know that each char in the array is 8 bits. Should I sum 4 of the characters up and toss it into an index of the unsigned int array or is it ok just to place each character in its separate array? Would summing four 8 bit characters up change their values into the array? I have read something about shifting characters, however, I am not sure exactly how to shift the four characters into one index of the unsigned int array.

text[i] is my array of characters.

```
uint32_t inputText[512];
for( i = 0; i < 504; i++)
{
  inputText[i] = (uint32_t)text[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cast seems fine; although, I'm not sure why you say `i < 504` when your array of `uint32_t`s is 512. (If you do want to only convert 504 values and you want a 512-length array, you might want to use `array[512] = {0}` to ensure the memory is zeroed out instead of the last 8 values being set to whatever was previously in the memory.) Nonetheless, it is perfectly safe to say: `SomeArrayOfLargerType[i] = (largerType_t)SomeArrayOfSmallerType[i]`, but bear in mind that how it is now, your binary will end up looking something like:

```
 0100 0001 -> 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0001
```

So, those 24 leading `0`s might be an undesired result.

As for summing up four characters, that will almost definitely not work out how you want; unless you literally want the sum like `0000 0001` (one) + `0000 0010` (two) = `0000 0100` (three). If you would instead want the previous example to produce `00000001 000000010`, then yes, you would need to apply shifts.

**UPDATE** - *Some information about shifting via example:*

The following would be an example of shifting:

```
uint32_t valueArray[FINAL_LENGTH] = {0};
int i;
for(i=0; i < TEXT_LENGTH; i++){ // text_length is the initial message/text length (512 bytes or something)
    int mode = i % 4; // 4-to-1 value storage ratio (4 uint8s being stored as 1 uint32)
    int writeLocation = (int)(i/4); // values will be truncated, so something like 3/4 = 0 (which is desired)
    switch(mode){
        case(0):
            // add to bottom 8-bits of index
            valueArray[writeLocation] = text[i];
            break;
        case(1):
            valueArray[writeLocation] |= (text[i] << 8); // shift to left by 8 bits to insert to second byte
            break;
        case(2):
            valueArray[writeLocation] |= (text[i] << 16); // shift to left by 16 bits to insert to third byte
            break;
        case(3):
            valueArray[writeLocation] |= (text[i] << 24); // shift to left by 24 bits to insert to fourth byte
            break;
        default:
            printf("Some error occurred here... If source has been modified, please check to make sure the number of case handlers == the possible values for mode.\n");
    }
}
```

You can see an example of that running here: https://ideone.com/OcDMoM (*Note, there is some runtime error when executing that on IDEOne. I haven't looked intensely for that issue, though, as the output still seems to be accurate and the code is just meant to serve as an example.*)

Essentially, because each byte is 8-bits, and you want to store the bytes in 4-byte chunks (32-bits each), you need four different cases for how far you shift. In the first case, the first 8-bits are filled in by a byte from the message. In the second case, the second 8-bits are filled in by the following byte in the message (*which is left shifted by 8-bits because that is the offset for the binary position*). And that continues for the remaining 2 bytes, and then it repeats starting at the next index of the initial message array.

When combining the bytes, `|=` is used because that will take what is already in uint32 and it will perform a bitwise OR on it, so the final values will combine into one single value.

So, to break down a simple example like what I had in my initial post, let's say I have `0000 0001` (one) and `0000 0010` (two), with an initial 16-bit integer to hold them `0000 0000 0000 0000`. The first byte is assigned to the 16-bit integer making it `0000 0000 0000 0001`. Then the second byte is left shifted by 8 making it `0000 0010 0000 0000`. Finally, the two are via a bitwise OR, so the 16-bit integer becomes: `0000 0010 0000 0001`.

In the case of a 32-bit integer to hold 4 bytes, that process will repeat 2 more times with 8 additional shifts, and then it will proceed to the next uint32 to repeat the process.

Hopefully that all makes sense. If not, I can try to clarify further.

Comment: I apparently do need to use shifts to get the CRC to match the teacher's answer. He told me to try to use 4 16-bit chunks to calculate the CRC per 64 bit line. However, the unsigned int needs to be 32 bits. I'm assuming I need to shift characters into the array to get it to 32 bits to create the chunks. Also, I feel like it would be good knowledge to have for the future. Would you mind helping me out with them?

Comment: @starlight, personally, I have never looked into the implementation of CRC checksums, so I cannot give you an exact answer for how that would work out (which is probably better, as the whole point of being in a course is figuring out how to do those things independently). However, I will give you a general example of how can do that shifting. Just give me a few minutes to update answer.

Comment: Thank you, I should be able to go from there! :)

Comment: @starlight, updated. If anything is unclear, let me know.